# Can I replace the Create Article option in knowledge tab with my custom "Go" button

Tags: knowledge

I want to build the exact page as the knowledge tab page but just want to replace the "Create Article" button with my custom "Go" button beside the search window. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you will be creating a Visualforce Page, then it is possible as you can name the button as you want. Otherwise, it is not possible as that page is a standard one.